# Mail/mime 'Bcc:' Address appending to 'From:' Address

Tags: php, email, mime, mime-mail

When using `Mail/mime` in php, I'm dispatching emails with one of the `Bcc` addresses appended to the `From` address.

```
$header = array(
        'From' => 'sales@example.co.uk',
        'Subject' => "Your new Email", 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    ); 

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => "\n"));
$mime->addBcc("admin@example.co.uk");
$mime->addBcc("HR@example.co.uk");
```

Initially, I had the Bcc: field with addresses separated by comma, in the header array.
Then I tried the above method.

Both resulted in the receiver's email being addressed From: `sales@example.co.uk HR@example.co.uk`

How do I achieve 2 Bcc Address on dispatch?

Comment: It's a long shot, but sounds to me like a line terminator issue. MIME normally uses `\r\n`, you only need `\n` when sending the email using Mail (see note at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.mail-mime.php). How about _not_ overriding the default `\r\n` in the Mail_mime constructor?

Comment: I've done so testing today at work. it seem's this issue is subjective to the specific 2nd email address that we are using.